A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed "
Getting an error while calling API from WCF service:

"A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond"

WCF uses http protocol and API is using https protocol.
below is the code:
var client = new HttpClient();              
var data = new Dictionary<string, string>();
data["client_id"] = "XXXX";
data["client_secret"] = "XXXX";
data["grant_type"] = "XXXXX";

using (HttpContent formContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(data))
{
    using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("https://api-cdt.maersk.com/oauth2/access_token", formContent).ConfigureAwait(false))
    {
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        var tokenClient = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TokenClient>(json);
        return tokenClient.access_token;
    }
}

I am expecting API call should get execute and get the access token.

The reason may be that you need to convert your URL string to a URI object.
Uri uri = new Uri("https://api-cdt.maersk.com/oauth2/access_token", UriKind.Absolute);

using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(uri, formContent).ConfigureAwait(false))
    {
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        var tokenClient = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TokenClient>(json);
        return tokenClient.access_token;
    }


